# How many cases I must solve to be ranked in new Tribunal in LoL?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have 57 cases solved, elo 2171 with 88% of accuracy and I'm still unranked. I'm curious how many cases until I am "ranked" **judge**. Anyone know anything more about it?

Comment: Depends on the region. Different people have different Elo ratings.  I believe 10,000 Elo put you in the top 300.

Comment: I believe only the top 1000 Tribunals have a rank displayed. (My evidence: I hovered around 950 for a while; if I missed a day, I'd drop to Unranked, after which I had to do very well the next day to become ranked again.) I'd also note that I'm just below 6000 elo and I'm ranked just below 700.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no clear guideline from Riot you can only estimate. 
One thing is certain: To become ranked you need to be in the **top 1000 Tribunal Ratings**.
Check this thread out at Western European Server where people compare their Ratings:
http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=896598

You'll see there that by estimation you need about 8k Rating to be close to becoming ranked. But that of course was 5 days ago and it will probably keep changing since it's a relatively small and apparently pretty competitive ladder.

It also depends on the region so the thread I gave you only refers to Europe West. But if you go through the posts a bit you will get the general idea.

Answer (score -3):

You need at *least* 100 with over 90% accuracy.

Comment: do you have a source for this?